# Fourier Transform of sin function

Tags: calculus

Hi there I'm trying to find the fourier transform of the following:
\begin{equation*}
x(t)  = \sin(\pi t + \pi).
\end{equation*}
From what I know, I would integrate this using: $FT =\int x(t)e^{-iwt} dt$.

I would also convert x(t) into complex exponential form. However I am confused how I go from here: I know it has something to do with dirac delta but I'm not entirely clued up on how to solve this integral using it. Any explanations would help a lot!

Thanks for your time

Comment: To do that rigorously you need to understand the notion of Schwartz space and tempered distributions, but formally speaking, after you write your sine function as complex exponential, the Fourier transform would look like the Fourier transform of the function 1 evaluated at certain point. This is where you used the fact that the Fourier transform of 1 is the Dirac delta function.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, you need to study the theory of Fourier transform on Schwartz functions and tempered distributions in order to do it properly, but let me try to sketch the proof.

> Definition 1 : Let $f$ be a function in the [Schwartz space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space), which I denote by $\mathcal{S}$. We say that $u$ is a tempered distribution if there exists constants $C,N>0$ such that 
>   $$|\langle u,\phi\rangle|\le C\sum_{|\alpha|\le N,|\beta|\le N}\|x^\alpha\partial^\beta\phi\|_{L^\infty}\quad\forall\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$$

Note that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the duality pairing of the tempered distribution with Schwartz functions. One can easily check that the Dirac delta function, $\delta$ and the function $1$ are both tempered distributions.

> Definition 2: We define the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution, $u$ to be the unique tempered distribution $\hat u$ such that
>   $$\langle \hat u,\phi\rangle=\langle u,\hat\phi\rangle\quad\forall\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$$

Since Schwartz functions are also $L^1$ functions, the Fourier transform of $\phi$, which I denote as $\hat\phi$ above is well-defined. Now, we compute the Fourier transform of $1$:(Here I use the fact that the inverse Fourier transform of a Schwartz function is well-defined.)
\begin{align}
\langle\hat 1,\phi\rangle & =\langle 1,\hat\phi\rangle & \text{[Definition 2]}\\
& =\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\hat\phi(\xi)d\xi\quad & \text{[definition of distributions]}\\
& =\phi(0) & \text{[definition of inverse Fourier transform]}\\
& =\delta(\phi) & \text{[definition of Dirac delta]}\\
& =\langle\delta,\phi\rangle
\end{align}

Thus, by writing sine function as a linear combination of complex exponential, the Fourier transform of sine function is a linear combination of Dirac delta functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this in my way. There are two useful identities:

1. $\mathcal{F}\{{e^{iw_0t}}\}=2\pi \delta(w-w_0)$
2. $sin{\theta}=\frac{1}{2i} ({e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}})$

The first identity can be proved by taking inverse Fourier transfer to both sides.
Now we can write
$$\mathcal{F}\{sin(\pi t+\pi)\}=\mathcal{F}\{\frac{1}{2i} ({e^{i(\pi t+\pi)}-e^{-i(\pi t+\pi)}})\}=\frac{1}{2i}e^{i\pi} \mathcal{F} \{e^{i \pi t} \}- \frac{1}{2i}e^{-i\pi} \mathcal{F} \{e^{-i \pi t}\} = \frac{1}{2i}e^{i\pi} 2\pi\delta(w-\pi)-\frac{1}{2i}e^{-i\pi} 2\pi\delta(w+\pi)$$

As expected, the distribution happens at frequency of $\pi$ and $-\pi$ with certain magnitude and phase.